# how to remove a specific character from a tuple using python

Tags: python, string, tuples

I have a tuple:

`tuple = ('one', ('two', 'three'))`

I want to print remove the `'` from this tuple so I can print it as `(one, (two, three))`.

I have tried this

```
tuple = str(tuple)
print tuple.strip(')
```

But I get this error:

```
    print tuple.strip(')
                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

How can I turn my tuple into the desired string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
t = ('one', ('two', 'three'))
t2 = str(t)       
print(t2.replace("'",""))
```

It's considered bad practice to use keywords like `tuple` as variable names, you might run into trouble with that.

Comment: yeah I just simplified my problem for this post and chose to use tuple to be clear. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 4):

You can print with replace:

```
print(str(tuple).replace("'", ''))
```

output

```
(one, (two, three))
```